# How to troubleshoot system halt on repeated launch of Sushi in Debian?

Tags: debian, gnome3, nautilus, sushi

This problem Of Gnome *Sushi* has persisted long time in Debian Stretch. 
It is connected to the preview manager, Sushi, in the file manager, which breaks the system

- if you type any other key before the loading preview window is successful.
- or you repetedly open Sushi with space - - I think the problem is connected with pressing some other key while the preview window of Sushi is not yet loaded.

I do not find the approriate bug report about the case [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&component=Crashers&product=nautilus) in the Nautilus bug tracker.
Procedure

1. Press <kbd>space</kbd> to preview a file, etc a big .ppt/.pdf/... file.
2. Try to move away from the file, while the system is loading the preview.
3. Result: keyboard is not sensititive any more, only mouse moves, but no TTY switch works etc.

Verified the problem with 10th Jan 2018 Debian version too in the second hardware.

OS: Linux Debian Stretch 9.1
Window manager: Gnome stable
Ticket: Gnome Nautilus [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/199)
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA R4028T

Comment: Let me guess: because of a bug?

Comment: @IporSircer Please, see the title again. How to troubleshoot this case such that we can understand how to describe the bug?

Comment: Nautilus had a lot of bugs last years, even in the "stable" releases. You have a good chance of finding a new or a reported one. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/page.cgi?id=browse.html&product=nautilus

Comment: @IporSircer I sent an issue report there, please see the body. Let's hope we get the problem more focused such that we can understand how it is there.